# C# convert stride/buffer/width/height to bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, writeablebitmap

I have an image width/height/stride and buffer.

How do I convert this information to a System.Drawing.Bitmap? Can I get the original image back if I have these 4 things?

Comment: You mean to say while uploading you want to save image in binary format into database and retrieve value and dispaly as a image  ?

Comment: What I mean is that someone has written a code to get the height/width/stride/buffer for a video camera. He now wants me to do stuff to it. I want to use bitmap images, and he uses a writeablebitmap and told me how to get the stride / width etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Bitmap` constructor overload, which requires everything you have (plus `PixelFormat`):

[`public Bitmap(int width, int height, int stride, PixelFormat format, IntPtr scan0);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx)

This might work (if `args.Buffer` is an array of blittable type, like `byte` for example):

```
Bitmap bitmap;
var gch = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(args.Buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
    bitmap = new Bitmap(
        args.Width, args.Height, args.Stride,
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb,
        gch.AddrOfPinnedObject());
}
finally
{
    gch.Free();
}
```

Update:

Probably it's better to copy image bytes to newly created `Bitmap` manually, because it seems like that constructors doesn't do that, and if `byte[]` array of image data gets garbage collected all sorts of bad things can happen.

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(args.Width, args.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
var data = bitmap.LockBits(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, args.Width, args.Height),
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

if(data.Stride == args.Stride)
{
    Marshal.Copy(args.Buffer, 0, data.Scan0, args.Stride * args.Height);
}
else
{
    int arrayOffset = 0;
    int imageOffset = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y < args.Height; ++y)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(args.Buffer, arrayOffset, (IntPtr)(((long)data.Scan0) + imageOffset), data.Stride);
        arrayOffset += args.Stride;
        imageOffset += data.Stride;
    }
}

bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
```

Comment: All I've been given is that I can find the stride/buffer etc in args
ie -> args.Buffer = buffer... args.Stride = stride etc

But using
Bitmap test = new Bitmap(args.Width, args.Height, args.Stride, PixelFormats.Rgb24, args.Buffer);

gives me an error :( I'm kinda new to image programming...

Comment: Would this work... well... get me somewhere...?

var test = BitmapFrame.Create(args.Width, args.Height, 300D, 300D, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null, args.Buffer, args.Stride);

Comment: what type is `args.Buffer`? `byte[]`? Also `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and `BitmapFrame` come from 2 different GUI frameworks, you must decide what to use.

Comment: Ok... I'll stick with Bitmap as that's what the rest of my code is in... I've already done the code, its just now putting it into his system... and yes, args.Buffer is byte[] which gives me the error that I need System.IntPtr... so I get the joys of looking up that conversion now too :)

Comment: Yeah that worked.

Gotta sort out the format, as currently its blue... guess he gave me the wrong info about the pixel format... and also, running the code now causes issues elsewhere in the program. :( Thanks for the help though! Hopefully I can sort out the other issues :)

Comment: The data.Buffer causes the error in your second code snippet... apparently BitmapData does not contain a Definition for Buffer

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you have the buffer as byte[], a width and the height + the pixelformat (stride)

```
    public Bitmap CreateBitmapFromRawDataBuffer(int width, int height, PixelFormat imagePixelFormat, byte[] buffer)
    {
        Size imageSize = new Size(width, height);

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height, imagePixelFormat);
        Rectangle wholeBitmap = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

        // Lock all bitmap's pixels.
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(wholeBitmap, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, imagePixelFormat);

        // Copy the buffer into bitmapData.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, buffer.Length);

        // Unlock  all bitmap's pixels.
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Simple, concise and blazing fast. Thank you !